# .Net 6 Blazor WebAssembly App api is not working without debugging mode but working in debugging mode

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

.Net 6 Blazor WebAssembly App **api** is not working without debugging mode but working in debugging mode.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAMMB.png)

without debugging mode getting the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uteho.png)

And also api not working after publishing in local iis.

I tried with a new project but new project is working fine.

Comment: I created new project with same structure. Then copy and replace the previous project files. New project is working as expected. And after publishing it's also working fine. But I still don't know what was the problem of first project.